# Matlab: spatial average in a 4d matrix (time, case, x, y)

Tags: matlab, average, netcdf

Here is my dataset:

pressure(time, case, x, y)

```
>> size(pressure)
ans =
   100     1    289   570
```

How to get a spatial nanmean pressure for x from 30 to 60 and y from 40 to 70 in each time step?

For example: a nanmean value for that particular region for each timestep from time 1 to time 100.

I tried this, "spatial_mean_pressure = nanmean(pressure(:,:,30:60,40:70))" It averaged the pressure in the timeserie. This is not the result I want.

```
>> size(spatial_mean_pressure)
ans =
1     1    31    31
```

I like to get the results like this:

```
>> size(spatial_mean_pressure)    
ans =
100     1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get a mean for an entire block of matrix. Therefore, you should apply `nanmean` twice and not once. Also, apply it along a particular dimension to get the desired result. I think this is what you want.

```
x=randi(10,[100 1 10 25]);
```

First take the mean along the third dimension.

```
mean_x_3=nanmean(x,3);
```

You would get an answer of size = `[100 1 1 25]`. Then take the mean along 4th dimension.

```
mean_x_4=nanmean(mean_x_3,4);
```

This should give you the desired answer. You can write this in one line as,

```
mean_x = nanmean(nanmean(x,3),4);
```

Comment: I got complete results in the following methods: method#1: mean_x = nanmean(nanmean(x,3),4); method#2: M = x(1:100, 1, 1:10, 1:25);
mean_xy = nanmean(reshape(M,size(M,3)*size(M,4),[]))';

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang please upvote or accept the answer if you found it useful so that it would be easier for others.